# How many builds will make a new chromium version number?

Tags: build, version, chromium

As you can see the Google Chromium browser will release a few builds (currently it's Version 32.0.1687.0 (231977)) every day.

I wonder what's the definition of a new version?

That is to say: I modified some parts and fixed some bugs, then commit the code then the build number increased to 231978, how they know they can release a higher version with increasing the normal version number to 33? Is there a principle or some practice?

Or it's nothing about the build, it's how many changes and new features finished that we can release a new version?

Comment: Off-topic, but I'm curious too.